# Can an Android Worker run without calling Application.onCreate?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm scheduling a unique [Periodic work](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/getting-started/define-work#schedule_periodic_work) which I'm guessing at some point will run even when my app is not running, not even in the background.

My question is, when my app is completely terminated and my worker gets launched by the OS, will my `Application.onCreate` method be called before my worker runs? Or will it run completely isolated from the app?

There are some dependencies initialized in my `Application.onCreate` method that are needed for my worker to run, so if my worker can run in complete isolation, then I'll have to set those up inside the worker itself. Though I'm not sure that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run your App. Don't worry. All event's like this will run your App and onCreate(). It applies to Manifest Broadcast receivers, AlarmManager timers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, when my app is completely terminated and my worker gets launched by the OS, will my Application.onCreate method be called before my worker runs? Or will it run completely isolated from the app?

Yes it will.

Any code you write will be run in its own Process for the OS to manage. [Per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application):

> The Application class, or your subclass of the Application class, is instantiated before any other class when the process for your application/package is created.

You should be able to test this with some Log statements in your Application and Worker classes. Just schedule your work for like 30 seconds into the future and then kill your process and see what happens.

Comment: That's not quite correct that the `Application.onCreate` is executed before all the things in the app's process. E.g. `ContentProvider`s and `AppComponentFactory` are instantiated and executed before the `Application`. Particularly `App Startup` library relies on this `ContentProvider`s behavior to do its job. Though it's correct that `Application.onCreate` will be called before `Worker` as the latter is created in the `SystemJobService` from inside the `WorkManager` implementation.